# invalid opcode The execution might have thrown

Tags: erc-20

I cannot call the settoken function

transact to TRUST.settoken errored: VM error: invalid opcode. invalid opcode The execution might have thrown. Debug the transaction to get more information.

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import"https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";

contract TRUST is Ownable{
    using SafeMath for uint;
    uint public free; 
    

    mapping (address => mapping(address => data[])) public _data;
    mapping (address => address[]) public fromaddr ;

    struct data{
        uint64 startTime;
        uint64 intervals;
        uint256 onceamount;
        uint256 alltoken;
        address ercaddr;
    }
    
    
    
    function _FREE (uint _free)public onlyOwner{
        free = _free;
    }
    
   function tokennum(address _from, address _to, address _tokenaddress)private view returns(uint e, uint ee){
      if(_data[_from][_to].length != 0){
        for(uint8 i; i <= _data[_from][_to].length; i++){
           if (_data[_from][_to][i].ercaddr == _tokenaddress){
               e++;
               ee = i;
           }
        }
      }
   }
    
    function settoken (address token ,address to ,uint64 startTime ,uint64 intervals ,uint256 onceamount ,uint256 alltoken)public payable{
        require (msg.value == free ,"free err");
        require(IERC20(token).transferFrom(msg.sender ,address(this) ,alltoken),"etc");
        require (uint(to) *uint(token) *startTime *onceamount *alltoken != 0 ,"input");
        uint e;
        uint ee;
        (e,ee) = tokennum(msg.sender , to , token);
        require(_data[msg.sender][to][ee].alltoken == 0);
        if (ee == 0){
            _data[msg.sender][to].push(data(startTime ,intervals ,onceamount ,alltoken ,token));
        }else {
            _data[msg.sender][to][ee] = data(startTime ,intervals ,onceamount ,alltoken ,token);
        }
        IERC20(token).transferFrom(msg.sender ,address(this) ,alltoken);
    }
 
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
for (uint8 i; i <= _data[_from][_to].length; i++)
```

To this:

```
for (uint8 i; i < _data[_from][_to].length; i++)
```

Otherwise, you are attempting to access the array `_data[_from][_to]` at an illegal index:

```
if (_data[_from][_to][i].ercaddr == _tokenaddress) ...
```

Side note: you may want to change `uint8` to `uint256` here, in order to avoid wrap-around.